# Intel AMT KVM: Accessing multiple servers behind one public IP address

Tags: remote-access, remote-control, kvm-switch, intel-amt

I have to host multiple servers in a collocation center which is distant over 250 km. I need to have as good remote control over the servers as possible. In other words, I need to be able to access BIOS of the servers, be able to turn the servers ON or OFF, or to remotely re-install the Operating System.

For this purpose the relatively fresh Intel vPro AMT KVM technology is just optimal and cost effective. I can access just one server over the public IP address of that server.

What I do not know is, how to access multiple servers via Intel vPro KVM, if they all are behind one public IP address. Will technologies like IP Address Translation or port forwarding work for me? Could you advise please, how to configure the network so, that I would be able to access any of the servers on the network if of course they all support Intel vPro AMT (and KVM)?

Comment: Did you find a solution to this?

Comment: Arya, yes I did. It is essential to establish a VPN network with the default gateway on the remote side, which is normally a firewall or a router. Then, it is possible to address the PCs through their private IP Addresses, which basically does the thing: it allows to access individual PCs through Intel KVM. Is my answer clear enough to you?

Comment: would I need a special router to do this?

Comment: Nope, you just need to know, whether your one, or the firewall supports VPN. You have find that in the documentation. Then, you will need to install a VPN client on your PC, and establish VPN network between your router/firewall. However, if you have a network on the remote side, you will probably use firewall appliance. Focus firstly on the firewall, because firewalls usually support creating VPN tunnels.

Answer (score 1):

There are two generic solutions to this, one which will work for you

1. Give each server its own normal (public) IP address. This is the way the Internet was designed, though we temporarily used all sorts of kludges when we ran out of IP v4 addresses. However it seems Intel-AMT does have IP v6 support, and in the last decades this replacement for IP v4 is gaining ground.
2. Access each server over a private (RFC1918) IP address **from the local network**. That adds one intermediate step: getting from your network onto the remove network as if you were locally present. A VPN will solve this.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Client Initiated Remote Access](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Client_Initiated_Remote_Access) (CIRA) in AMT whereby the machine connects to a remote server (even on the Internet) through which you can control it.

A good server to handle this (open source and free) is [MeshCentral](https://www.meshcommander.com/meshcentral2).